# Android library/SDK/API for iOS like fileviewer

Tags: android, viewer, formats

There are many questions about this subject, but none has come to the correct answer.

In summary, what out-of-the-box library/SDK provides finished/usable code for Building an Android App that can View: doc,docx,xls,xlsx,ppt, pptx, and PDF?

- Redirecting to Apache POI is not the answer, as it doesn't provide
  this functionality, only reading (some) these formats, display is required;
- Redirecting to all kinds of apps in the appstore is not the answer: yes you can use intents to open the file formats in these apps, but thats not within our own app;
- Redirecting to a transformation code is not the answer, as this is not possible within Android. (doc to html and then to PDF and use a PDF viewer? I only saw partial/buggy answers);
- Using Google Docs or other cloud solutions to display is not possible, offline usage is required;

Isn't there a company that provides native libraries, or an open source project/app that is implementing this?

Comment: I have been on the lookout for this as well. I have alow priority project that could be greatly enhanced if this were available. So far the best thing I could come up with is creating a PDF conversion service inside my environment with PHP/LibreOffice/Apache. Does your "offline" usage mean disconnected from all networks or limited to something like a corporate network?

Comment: Correct, "offline" in the sense as no network connection (so on device display, not via webview like solutions).

I have heard that libreoffice is coming to Android, first as a document viewer, maybe that's providing a reusable library?
http://liliputing.com/2012/07/libreoffice-coming-to-android-heres-what-it-looks-like-so-far.html

Comment: Did you get any solution on this?

Comment: Hi Dennis, if u get the solution, pls share it..

Comment: Hi Dennis ,any solutions you got? please share

Comment: Hi Dennis, u got any solutions for these?